# 6502 assembler random number problems

Tags: assembly, 6502

I am playing around with 6502 assembler here: http://skilldrick.github.io/easy6502

I have made this that just puts a random color pixel in a random place on the screen:

```
LDY #$00    ; Clear Y

loop:
 JSR genPos ; Put new position in memory
 LDA $fe    ; Get random number for color
 STA ($10), Y   ; Put pixel on screen
 JMP loop

genPos:
 STA $10    ; Store accumulator in low
 LDA $fe    ; Get new random number (WHY, oh why?)
 AND #$03   ; Mask out low two bits (=numbers 0-3)
 CLC        ; Clear carry flag
 ADC #2     ; Add 2 (= numbers 2-5)
 STA $11    ; Store number in high
 RTS
```

I am trying to use as few instructions as possible. My problem is that if I don't put an extra `LDA $fe` in the `genPos` sub routine the pixels are drawn in a very strange pattern where if I do have the extra LDA the code works perfectly. I can't comprehend why - can anyone give me a hint?

Regards,
Jacob

Comment: Yeah - 2 bytes. Low is in $10, high in $11. What I don't understand is that the random number in the accumulator (used for the color in the previous loop) should make a fine low byte for the screen address.

Comment: @i486: @jriff linked the JavaScript emulator he's using. It has random numbers at `$fe` and keyboard input at `$ff`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It already is making a fine low byte! This line:

```
LDA $fe    ; Get new random number (WHY, oh why?)
```

goes on to decide the *high* byte, and if you don't generate a new random number, the `y` value will be dependent on the **lowest two bits** of the `x` value, causing the diagonals you're seeing: the value of `x & 3` always equals which segment of screen the value is being drawn on, meaning you get a pattern like

```
█   █   █   █   █   █   █   █    \
█   █   █   █   █   █   █   █     |
█   █   █   █   █   █   █   █     |  x & 3 == 0  in $200-$2FF
█   █   █   █   █   █   █   █     |
█   █   █   █   █   █   █   █    /
 █   █   █   █   █   █   █   █   \
 █   █   █   █   █   █   █   █    |
 █   █   █   █   █   █   █   █    |  x & 3 == 1  in $300-$3FF
 █   █   █   █   █   █   █   █    |
 █   █   █   █   █   █   █   █   /
  █   █   █   █   █   █   █   █  \
  █   █   █   █   █   █   █   █   |
  █   █   █   █   █   █   █   █   |  x & 3 == 2  in $400-$4FF
  █   █   █   █   █   █   █   █   |
  █   █   █   █   █   █   █   █  /
   █   █   █   █   █   █   █   █ \
   █   █   █   █   █   █   █   █  |
   █   █   █   █   █   █   █   █  |  x & 3 == 3  in $500-$5FF
   █   █   █   █   █   █   █   █  |
   █   █   █   █   █   █   █   █ /
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your research and the explanation. I get it now.

Answer (score 6):

The algorithm applied with the LDA is:

```
[random 1] -> [11:10]
[random 1] -> [10]
[random 2]&3 + 2 -> [11]
(repeat)
```

If you fail to reload `a` from $fe then you're doing:

```
[random 1] -> [11:10]
[ramdom 1] -> [10]
[random 1]&3 + 2 -> [11]
(repeat)
```

Therefore both the low and high byte of the addressed pixel is a function of the same random number. They're not independent. That creates a correlation between them. Which manifests itself in the pattern you see. If your pretend screen were 256 pixels wide it'd be a direct diagonal; based on the fact that you see 8 strips I can deduce that your output must actually be 256/8 = 32 pixels wide.

The issue isn't that you're wrong to say that "the random number in the accumulator ... should make a fine low byte for the screen address." it's that you're then also using it for the high byte. You're using it for both. The high byte is a direct function of the low byte. So there are a bunch of high bytes you'll never hit because they don't satisfy the constraint that `high=(low&3)+2`. Those pixels remain unlit.

Comment: Thank you SO much for the explanation. I'm sorry that I can't split the kudos between you and Mauris  - you both deserve it.

Comment: Instead somebody has decided to downvote it. Is it that poorly written?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is actually pretty simple. When you load anything into the accumulator, the accumulator is nothing more than a copy of whatever was there at the time. There's a fundamental rule of registers that if you don't change them, their value will stay the same indefinitely.

Although the value stored at `$fe` changes every cycle, whatever is in the accumulator after you load from `$fe` *will not change unless you use another instruction to alter the contents of the accumulator.* It's no different from this:

```
LDA $0200
INC $0200 ;the value at $0200 is now 1 higher than the accumulator.
```

Because of this, if you never reload the accumulator with a new random value, the value you're storing as the high byte is based on the value you used for the low byte.